# how can I pipe the output of "wc" to an inequality (-gt) without using "if;then" syntax?

Tags: bash, pipe

I want to count the number of files matching a pattern at a depth of 1, and compare it with a number, e.g. to see if I have 3 or more such files. However, I want to do this without using the if/then syntax.

i.e. something like this:

```bsh
ls -1q -d *patternX* | wc -l | [ -ge 3]
```

I'd appreciate very much if someone could let me know if there's a way to escape using the if/then syntax. Thanks!

Comment: _"I **want** to do this without using the if/then syntax"_ -- So, is there some reason to not use a construct made exactly for conditional execution if conditional execution is what you want/need to do? If you've just arbitrarily decided that the obvious solution is not acceptable, than how can we know if some other solution would also not be acceptable?

Comment: As commented already, if you have any constraints (i.e., "not using ''if'"), please explain why such a constraint exists. We cannot offer much help if you provide arbitrary constraints that limit how we can help.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for commenting. I'm familiar with the if/then syntax and have used it in the past. I was curious whether the same aim could be achieved this way (piping "directly" into an inequality comparison), and therefore asked the question in the title out of pure curiosity/academic interest.

Comment: @C.M. Thanks for commenting. I asked the question in the title not out of necessity, but out of pure curiosity/academic interest. I keep learning new things everyday; I wondered whether it could be done this way and thought if anyone knew, it would be someone on this site, and therefore I asked.

Comment: @abra: I suggest you edit your question to indicate that, so it's up front instead of someone having to read through the comments down here. I will note, however, that your "compare it ... and **_if_** ..." statements make it very difficult to do without some kind of logic branching (i.e., using `if`), as your requirement itself has an "if". You can save the wc output to a shell variable, but without knowing more about your goal, that may be useless. (I.E., let's say you _can_ `[ $result -gt 3 ]` ... but what do you want to _do_ with the comparison? it will just be a true/false boolean value.)

Comment: (and to add given comments posted to some answers): Just having stating it in the title is not enough. The title often only gets the attention of those who want to help, or those seeking a solution to a similar/identical problem. Then they read the body of the question to find out the full _details_--even ones already stated in the title.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to want to count the number of names matching `*patternX*` and then test whether that is greater than or equal to three.

This is best done like so:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

set -- *patternX*
if [ "$#" -ge 3 ]; then
    echo 'More than 2 names match the pattern'
fi
```

This is setting the positional parameters to the names matching the pattern.  The number of matching names would be kept in `$#`.  The `nullglob` option is set so that if there are no names matching, the pattern is removed completely rather than kept unexpanded.

You could also use a named array to store the matching names:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

names=(*patternX*)
if [ "${#names[@]}" -ge 3 ]; then
    echo 'More than 2 names match the pattern'
fi
```

See also [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

---

Without the words `if` and `then`:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

set -- *patternX*
[ "$#" -ge 3 ] && echo 'More than 2 names match the pattern'
```

A similar approach using `awk`:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

awk 'BEGIN { if (ARGC > 3) print "more than 2" }' *patternX*
```

Note that `ARGC` in `awk` also accounts for the command name (what would be `$0` in the shell).

Comment: Hi! Thank you, but my question specifically asks whether it is possible to do this without using the "if;then" syntax, so this isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: @abra See updated answer

Comment: Thank you! Your second suggestion doesn't have "if" and "then", but it's mostly a technicality as the underlying method is similar. As I mentioned in the title, I am looking for a syntax (if possible) where I can pipe the output of a command (like wc) directly into an inequality operation.

Comment: @abra The issue is that the operation that you seem to want to do, i.e. count names matching a pattern, should not generally be done with `ls` and `wc`.

Comment: Tests do not read stdin, so you need something inside the test that *does* read the pipe: `echo 7 | [ $( cat ) -ge 6 ] && echo Bigger || echo Not`.

Comment: @abra so, like `[ "$(... | wc)" -ge 3 ]`?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant thanks, much closer to what I want, but I would want the command to print 0 or 1 at the end; if I cut off the " &&...." part of your suggestion, it doesn't return any output

Comment: Test returns a true (0) false (1) status. `echo 7 | [ $( cat ) -ge 6 ]; echo $?`.

Comment: @abra please edit your question and add all of these requirements. What you are asking for is not a standard feature and most of us are happy using either `if/else` or `condition && foo || bar` constructs so if you cannot use that we need to know.

Comment: @terdon the title of the question mentions all these requirements. The question is less out of necessity and more out of curiosity because it's the syntax that came first/intuitively to my mind, but I couldn't find any solutions along those lines. So I thought I'd consult the community since I'm a relative beginner and see if it's possible. I'm not necessarily asking if it's the best/most common solution.

Comment: @abra So you don't need to count the number of files in a directory in a correct way, or even interested in how that should be done in a portable and idiomatic way? You're just interested in how to do something that nobody would want to do, just to see whether it's possible?

Comment: @Kusalananda It's not that I'm uninterested in how to do it the correct way. I'm familiar with the if/then syntax and have used it in the past. I was curious whether the same aim could be achieved this way, and therefore asked. I assumed this was a place where questions of pure curiosity/academic interest were welcome.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, you'd typically use an anonymous function such as:

```
()(( $# >= 3 )) *patternX*(N)
```

That calls an anonymous function whose body is `(( $# >= 3 ))` (which returns *true* if the number of arguments is 3 or more), with the expansion of the `*patternX*(N)` glob as arguments.

`(N)` is to enable the `nullglob` option for that glob so that the glob expands to nothing instead of reporting an error if there's no matching file.

A more literal answer to what you're asking could be:

```
ls -1q -d -- *patternX* | wc -l | xargs -IN test N -ge 3
```

(in any shell, but beware behaviour varies between shell when the pattern doesn't match any file).

Or:

```
[ "$(( $(ls -1q -d -- *patternX* | wc -l) ))" -ge 3 ]
```

(in any POSIX or Korn-like shell)

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to believe that this is a real world problem, but here's one solution:

```
ls -1q -d *patternX* | wc -l | egrep '^[3-9][0-9]*|[0-9][0-9]+' && echo JA
```